# CI upload using jQuery bpopup when pops up logs out user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, bpopup

I am using jQuery bpopup plugin with codeigniter. When I click on a upload button a popup pops up for which I am using bpopup but when a popup pops up the user is logged out. I have tried many things but none worked. Below is my HTML code:

```
<div id="popup" style="display:none; background:#FFF; width: 1100px; height:450px; overflow-y:scroll; border-radius: 9px;">
    <div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-12">         
    <div class="block-flat">
    <div class="header">                            
        <h3><strong>Uploaded Files</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="uploadedFiles">
        </div>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
            <?php echo form_upload('','','id="userfile"'); ?>
            <?php echo (isset($error)) ? $error : ''; ?>                        
            <?php echo form_button(array('content'=> 'Upload', 'id'=>'upload-file', 'class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary')); ?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
       </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the jQuery:

```
function uploadpopup(id){
    $('#popup').bPopup({
        easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
        speed: 650,
        transition: 'slideDown'         
    });
}
```

Comment: Nothing in this code would cause that issue.

Comment: When I remove <?php echo form_upload('','','id="userfile"'); ?> the popup works fine.

Comment: Wait, are you saying the popup CAUSES the user to get logged out, or it doesn't work when the user is logged out? Your question is not clear.

Comment: even if I add a normal html code 
<input type="file" name="btn-primary" value="" id="userfile" />
it logs out 
I know it sounds a bit strange but that is whats happening. :(

Comment: It causes the user to get logged out.